# How to find the angle approximation of incidence for a simple pendulum undergoing SHM using Taylor series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators, approximations

I am a high school student in the process of writing his physics report. My investigation is quite simple and it is finding the relationship between time period and length of a string in a simple pendulum experiment. I am planning on going a bit more into depth so thought about talking about the angle approximation in order to have the relationship for $T^2= L$. I found on the internet that Taylor series is possible for this approximation but because I haven’t covered Taylor series in school, I didn’t have an idea. If you can please briefly explain how this can be used, that will be very helpful. (Also if you think of something that could be taken a bit into depth about this experiment please let me know)

Comment: There is a quite detailed explanation at [Pendulum (mathematics) - Arbitrary-amplitude period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period)

Comment: I would suggest making measurements showing how the angle affects the period of the motion, and that they diverge from the simple prediction as the angle increases. If they match the Taylor series, good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer @Peter , this was my previous essay for different angles but I decided on doing length because it’s simpler for a student like me that doesn’t want to get to a lot of math. Therefore I wanted to explain the relationship briefly. Would that be possible? And can you please explain how you do that because I saw the website and didn’t quite  understand.

Comment: The link that @ThomasFritsch has posted is fascinating, and I'm happy to see it.  You might not be as happy as I.   In that article you might look at the section entitled [Small Angle Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Small-angle_approximation).  Here a (Taylor) series approximation is used at the beginning instead of at the end as the other sections do.   It's not explicitly stated, though.  It's the expression $\sin\theta\approx = \theta$.   [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions)